# Splitting an image during runtime

Tags: .net, image, split

I have an image such as this:
[image]

I want to have it so I can use these images for different buttons and other parts without having to split the image myself.  I've seen lots of games and programs do this without needing to split it.  How would I do this?  I'm using VB.net so any .net examples are appreciated!

You can see an example here:

[image]

This image is used as a minimap in a game I play, the different pieces are cut at runtime.

Comment: No, that's impossible. Other games and programs can't use individual images from that strip *"without needing to split it"*. Why do you prefer to use an image strip like that, instead of individual images assigned to controls?

Comment: I'm not asking for another solution.  I'm asking for help with the subject at hand.  Don't assume I want something else please.

Comment: I asked *why* you preferred your way, not assumed that you wanted something else. Not sure if I want to answer this, my answer might not be good enough for you.

Comment: Regardless of why, I do.  I truly don't care if you answer.  If it's right, I'll check it.  If it's not, you might get a vote if it's helpful or close.

Comment: FYI: 11 times out of 10, it helps you to get better answers if you're A) nicer to people asking simple questions and B) willing to provide some background information on what you're hoping to accomplish. Don't be so quick to assume people are trying to talk you *out* of what you want to do. It's way easier for me to provide detailed, specific advice and relevant code snippets if I understand exactly what someone is trying to accomplish. Your loss.

Comment: I explained why I needed it.  The way you interpret a post or comment is based on your own reading.  None of my posts were meant to be read with a harsh tone.  I used my manners and acted respectful.  I'm sorry if you read my posts with that "angry voice" in your head :)  I do it too sometimes.  Just always assume a post or comment has been posted with that "happy voice".  It makes the angry ones sound funny and everything else fits :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any way around splitting the image yourself. *Something* has to extract those individual images out of the strip so that you can use them independently.

You apparently take offense at the suggestion of (or even inquiry into) any alternative approaches, so I guess I'll skip that part of my answer...

The easiest way to split this up in .NET is using the [`Graphics` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx). which wraps GDI+ and provides several useful drawing-related functions. The most important one here is [`DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx), which provides several different overloads that allow you to specify the dimensions of the region inside the *source* image to draw from. By varying these coordinates, you can extract each of the individual images in your strip by drawing them into a new [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx). And once you have the `Bitmap`, you can either assign that to a control, save it to disk, or do whatever else you want with it.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted.  That wasn't so hard see?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in WPF:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = @"Imagestrip1600x16.png";
        var output = @"IconsFolder";
        using (Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(
            file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(
                imageStreamSource,
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapSource.PixelWidth / 16; i++)
            {
                CroppedBitmap croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(
                    bitmapSource,
                    new Int32Rect(i * 16, 0, 16, 16));

                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(croppedBitmap);
                encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
                var fileName = Path.Combine(output, i.ToString() + ".png");
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```